# Ant & Mercurial

Tags: java, ant, mercurial

I am trying to add some tag information in my ant script using the following target but I get an error (Result=-1) and hg tells me it does not recognise the command:

```
<target name="-post-init">
    <exec outputproperty="hg.tag" executable="hg">
        <arg value="parents --template {latesttag}+{latesttagdistance}" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

If I only include `value="parents"` it works fine.
If I run the command line `hg parents --template {latesttag}+{latesttagdistance}` it works fine too.

Any ideas on what is wrong in my syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just tried this and it works fine:

```
    <exec outputproperty="hg.tag" executable="hg">
        <arg value="parents" />
        <arg value="--template" />
        <arg value="{latesttag}+{latesttagdistance}" />
    </exec>
```

I needed to split the arguments.